# Different combinations of numbers inserted as loop variables

Tags: matlab, loops

I have some simple MATLAB code,

There main code requires other files, but here is the idea:

```
for i = [1]
    for kk = [21 23 28];
        for ii = [23 28];
            K=i; 

            xinit = [data(:,kk),data(:,ii),data(:,3),data(:,18),data(:,5)];
            yinit = data(:,16);
            H = eye(5); 
        end 
    end 
end
```

Say that I want to input the different combinations of the numbers 21, 22, 23 into the code like so:

- 21 instead of kk and simultaneously 23 instead of ii,
- Then 21 instead of kk and simultaneously 28 instead of ii,
- Then 23 instead of kk and simultaneously 28 instead of ii,

I know the above code it wrong, is there an easy fix?

My actual problem has 12 different data sets and I need the combinations of all of them so I would greatly appreciate a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code only need those 3 cases? or do you have a more general approach? Because if its just those 3, just write 3 lines of code, without a loop.

Comment: Yes, sorry Ander Biguri, I could really do with a general case so I could have say many numbers and many combinations.

Comment: The problem is that you gave an example, but you did not explain the logic. is `kk` always 3 values? is `ii` always 2 values? Are the values of `ii` always the last `n-1` from `kk`? Explain the logic, otherwise we are just stabbing in the dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method that fits your numbers (but not sure if its  right, you need to explain more) is:

```
myrandomnumbers=[3 5 9 12 24];
for kk=1:length(myrandomnumbers)-1
   for ii=2:length(myrandomnumbers)
       // your stuff
         myrandomnumbers(kk)
         myrandomnumbers(ii)
   end
end
```

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar for now, you are still deciding not to explain how to work with those numbers. Either explain the logic, or you dont get help.

Comment: Ok here is my logic, I am doing some regression analysis, I have many different variables and these are split into categories, then each variable is given a number, i want to do joint hypothesis tests for the variables within the same category.

Comment: So the question is now edited with numbers not in order. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Please, take 5 minutes and read my coments. Explain the logic behidn your choice, not change the numbers. Chaning the numbers doesn tsuddenly explain the logic of how you match the pairs. Does my edit work?